# time series smoothing techniques

Tags: time-series

I am currently analyzing time series data relating to financial observations (revenue and number of deposits in particular). I would like to smoothen the data because a lot of outliers are present.

Which is the most suitable smoothing filter in this case? I have read about Spencer's 15 point moving average, Henderson's moving average, exponential smoothing and a number of other techniques but I am not sure which would be best to stabilize the data.

Comment: What makes you think that there is some **most suitable** filter to remove outliers in financial data?

Comment: I am just trying to see which filter I should use. Or in other words, is there a way to check which filter fits my data better? ( which filter would retain as much information as possible while removing any large outliers that are effecting the predictions in a negative way?)

Comment: Define "fits" and "better" and "information" and "negative way". By the way it is "affecting" not "effecting".

Comment: And if you still don't see what's wrong with your question, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet. I think the best-fit line fits all four data sets **very well**!

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say, thank you for your help